Finding the column closest to a given column name
I have a dataframe in R that looks like this:
sample_df = data.frame(mondaya = c(1,1,1), tuesday_b = c(2,2,2), mondayb = c(1,1,1))

I want to find the column with the name closest to "monday" and make it say "monday_a".
Is there some standard way to do this in R? I am using an indirect way:
library(stringdist)

distances <- stringdist("monday", colnames(sample_df))

closest_col_index <- which.min(distances)

colnames(sample_df)[closest_col_index] <- "monday_a"


For most stringdist::stringdist-metrics (incl. the default optimal string aligment) you'd get the same result for both mondaya & mondayb; and which.min() returns index for the first minimum (i.e. the leftmost column with min. distance). Is this desired behaviour?  Depending on the metric, either of those could be closer to monday . If it doesn't really matter and you just have to pick something, there's adist() for Levenshtein distance.

What about adist?
> d <- adist(names(sample_df), "monday")

> sample_df[,d == min(d)]
  mondaya mondayb
1       1       1
2       1       1
3       1       1


Use Regular Expressions:
day_name <- '(sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday)(?!_)'
names(sample_df) <- sub(day_name, "\\1_", names(sample_df), perl=TRUE)
sample_df

  monday_a tuesday_b monday_b
1        1         2        1
2        1         2        1
3        1         2        1

